# SQL query for calculate cont of orders for each day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

Have a table:

```
order_id | time_order
1 | 2018-10-10 12:22:05
2 | 2018-10-11 05:22:05
4 | 2018-10-12 07:22:05
5 | 2018-10-12 15:25:05
...
```

I need to calculate orders count for each day in time interval and make a string like $str = '1, 1, 2, 0...'. If no orders some of days - 0.

Trying query like this:

```
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE DATE(time_order) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY GROUP BY time_order");
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query) )
{
    $str .= ','.json_encode($row,true);
}
```

But result is 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1...

Please, advise how to make right query?

Thanx!

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT DATE(time_order), COUNT(*)
FROM orders
WHERE DATE(time_order) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(time_order);
```

That is, your version is outputting the date for each `time_order`.  However, the `GROUP BY` includes the time, so you are getting a row for each date/time.

Comment: But how to receive result like 1,2,0,1,0,4? 0 - if no orders on some dates in time interval (no records with that date)? 1 | 2018-10-10 2 || 2018-10-11 3 ||no data|| 2018-10-13 4 || 2018-10-13